# How to map variable and view in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, layout-inflater

I have a list of objects, I set them to view and insert to layout

But I don't know how to identify which view for which object

Is it possible to add additional attribute to view before I insert it to layout?

For example:

```
LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(this);

HashMap<String, String> hm=new HashMap<String, String>();
hm.put("key1", "value 1");
hm.put("key2", "value 2");
hm.put("key3", "value 3");

for(String key: hm.keySet())
{
    View oneItem=inflater.inflate(R.layout.oneItem, linearlayout, false);
    TextView tv=(TextView)oneItem.findViewById(R.id.value);
    tv.setText(hm.get(key));

    //Is there any something like this?
    //oneItem.putExtra("id", key);
    //oneItem.setAttribute("id", key);

    linearlayout.addView(oneItem);
}
```

Comment: used `setTag()` and `getTag()` for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(String key: hm.keySet())
{
    View oneItem=inflater.inflate(R.layout.oneItem, linearlayout, false);
    TextView tv=(TextView)oneItem.findViewById(R.id.value);
    tv.setText(hm.get(key));

    oneItem.setTag(hm.get(key));

    linearlayout.addView(oneItem);
}
```

**Now whenever you find that item you can find like**

```
View view=linearlayout.getTag(hm.get(key));
```

Comment: I don't understand why 'oneItem.setTag(hm.get(key));' set a string, and it return a view `View view=linearlayout.getTag(hm.get(key));`, I think I should use `oneItem.setTag(key)`, and then use `hm.get(v.getTag())` in OnClickListener of each oneItem.

Comment: How about if I want to set more attribute to the view? I tried `oneItem.setTag(1,"attr1"); oneItem.setTag(2,"attr2");`, but the app will crash

Comment: @CLSo That's not possible with `HashMap`.

Comment: That is possible, I just need to convert the object to string `hm.get(v.getTag()+"")`